# Foreach PHP only inserts last item in db

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, foreach, insert-into

i allready found some answers at other topics but not a working answer for my situation. 
I'm having some troubles with inserting elements of an array into my DB. (SQL Server). When using a foreach loop in PHP the loop only inserts last element of the array into db, but when i `printr($arrayname)` it shows the correct both elements.

Here's some of the code.

***First i do a select to assign some variables:*** (the subquery is for removing ',' in the select)

```
$sql="SELECT ... FROM ...";
$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) { 

$sql.=$id.","; 
 }         
$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).")"; 

     if ($query){

         while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

         $variable=$row['rowname'];

        }
    }
```

So far so good, did an echo on the `$variable` to test if it prints both row records, and it did.

***Than i do the INSERT:***

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) { 

print_r($id);

$sql="INSERT INTO() ... VALUES ('$value')";
    $query= sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
}
```

Here's where it goes wrong, again i did a `print($id)` to test and see the values. 
It prints both values but only inserts the last element (`$variablename`) of array `$id`.

Please, what am i doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` in your script after `<?php` on top and check the actual errors. Please do and try

Comment: INSERT's must be inside while loop, not outside, otherwhise on $variable will be assigned last value from the loop.

Comment: Do you have some typos? You use `$sql2` but the query is called `$sql`, you use `$variablename` which should be `$value`?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you assign the sql query to `$sql`, but pass `$sql2` to `sqlsrv_query`?

Comment: @Anant error_reporting is on. Shows nothing though..

Comment: @mitkosoft did try that as well, but still only inserting last element.:/

Comment: @BasvanStein Sharp ;) .. i edited the question, but still not working correctly after changing the typo.

Comment: Did you check the result of the query? It might be that your query fails, for example you do not escape your variable in the query which might lead to sql injection and you will get a failed query (no error message) when there is a ' in your variable.

Comment: @BasvanStein Hi Bas, yes i did. But i got it working now.

Comment: @mitkosoft You we're right, i just orderded the while loop incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) { 

$sql.=$id.","; 
  }         
$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).")"; 
$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

    if ($query){

     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

     $variable=$row['rowname'];

     $sql2="INSERT INTO ()";
     $stmt= sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));


 }
}
```